# How to transfer shell script case statement into perl script

Tags: linux, perl, shell

How to write perl script for the below case stmt of shell script

```
sciptname=$0
case ${sciptname} in
  /*) scriptlocation=`dirname ${sciptname}`;;
   *) scriptlocation=`dirname ${pwd}/${sciptname}`;;
esac
```

Comment: @Raju: Switch.pm was removed from Perl in version 5.14. And even before that it was a source filter and therefore not recommended for production code. Please don't suggest that people use it.

Comment: I had remove my suggestion @DaveCross.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) library function `abs_path`.

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $script_location = abs_path( $0 );
```

Comment: thank u for ur solution, This i know.. But i want transfer/change code as its in case stmt to perle.. plz shere ur thougts

Comment: You can eliminate the case statement entirely by using `abs_path`.

Comment: If for some reason, you insist on the branching logic, you can use http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html, `$ENV{PWD}`, and an `if ( $0 =~ m|/| ) { # there is a slash } else { there isn't }`